# Bitbucket server and Teamcity - How to auto update feature branch with target branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, teamcity, bitbucket-server

I have been searching a lot for ways to **auto merge** the target Git branch into a feature branch in a pull request every time the target branch is updated with **Bitbucket server and Teamcity**. I have tried using +refs/pull-requests/*/merged as a VCS trigger but it seems that Bitbucket is not creating branches under refs/pull-requests/*.
I have also tried the Teamcity automatic merge feature but the only guides you can find is how to merge from some branch specification to a fixed branch eg integration branch. I have tried setting the target branch using %teamcity.build.branch% as:

[image: Teamcity automatic merge]

Still the merge commit is never happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am in the same boat. Made some progress with the pull request build feature (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html), but the behavior is still not 100% as expected.